# Android app architecture - how avoid fragment-service code duplication

Tags: android, architecture, android-fragments

My app has several `Fragments`. Each `Fragment` starts a `Service` that makes a GET request for a  resource from a server. Each response is a json array which is parsed into objects and saved into a database table, after which an `Intent` is broadcast to the Fragment that started  the service to query the table in question and display the objects in a list. So, each fragment-service-dbtable deals with a unique type of object, but other than that, the code is basically identical across each Fragment-Service pair:

```
NewsFragment, NewsPostsRequestService (deals with NewsPostObjects)
UserFragment, UserRequestService (deals with UserObjects)
FavoritesFragment, FavoritesRequestServices (deals with FavsObjects)
```

et cetera.

How can I avoid code duplication, so that one fragment and one service can be used for all requests? One options is to pass in a state as a parameter:

```
CustomFragment fragment = CustomFragment.newInstate(NewsState);
```

and then do (pseudo-code):

```
if(mState==NEWS) apiRequest("/news")
else if(mState==USERS) apiRequest("/users")
```

and so on.

However, what I ideally would like a solution where the fragment and service are completely independent of which resource their requesting, db table their saving to and object type their dealing, and new requests can easily be added. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I have some questions about your architecture decisions. Why do you need the service? Can't you load the data simply using an AsyncTask? And why do you need to store the data in Database? Does the data need to be persistent?

Comment: @Sameer. I use a Service to keep the query task completion independent of the Activity, so in case the Activity is shut down by the System the job can still complete. Yes, data needs to be persistent between user sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you should be able to solve that with inheritance. Implement AbstractService and AbstractFragment for the common code and then have abstract methods in each for the stuff that changes.

```
AbstractFragment<T>
AbstractPostsRequestService<T>
apiRequest(getRequestPath())
abstract String getRequestPath();


NewsFragment extends AbstractFragment<NewsPostObjects>
NewsPostsRequestService extends AbstractPostsRequestsService<NewsPostObjects>
String getRequestPath() {return "/news";}
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes that's one option, but it still involves some method code duplication in the implemented methods. Is there a way that would allow me to just specify parsed object type, db table and the request String?